# Broadcast receiver continue after application leave

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, ondestroy

I have a problem I can not solve, the broadcast receiver of my application continues to run when I leave my application.  I have to forcibly stop the application manually, whereas I are closed;
Thank you for your help. Here is my manifest, and my receiver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.locateit.antholife.locateit">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/locate"
    android:label="@string/app_nameprincipal"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Changelog"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_changelog"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBfmF3WWxsPhufZR5keiDNRy-33hJI1rvM" />

    <activity
        android:name=".lequipe"
        android:label="@string/nomequipe" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Setting"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_setting" />
    <activity android:name=".MDPinterne"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_mdpsecure" />
    <activity android:name=".Bluetooth"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_bluetooth" />

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

    <activity android:name=".Smsconnection"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gsm" >

    </activity>
</application>
```

and myreceiver :

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public MyReceiver() {
}

public int lock = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    if (extra != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extra.get("pdus");
        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        }
        if (messages.length > -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                String messageBody = messages[i].getMessageBody();
                String phoneNumber = messages[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Expéditeur:" + "\n" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Message : " + "\n" + messageBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (messageBody.equals("CS")) {

                    lock = 1;
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("appSharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("lockphone", phoneNumber);
                    editor.putInt("locksecurity", lock);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Association réussie !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "L'option Connexion GSM est maintenant désactivée.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
             /**   else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Echec de l'association !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Merci de renseigner un numéro correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } **/
            }
        }
    }
  }



 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `MyReceiver` registered in the manifest. Therefore, it is set up to receive broadcasts all the time.

If you want to only receive broadcasts some of the time, either:

- Use `registerReceiver()` and `unregisterReceiver()` on some `Context`, eliminating your `<receiver>` element from the manifest, or
- Use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to enable or disable the `<receiver>` as appropriate

As an example of the former, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v7.2/Intents/OnBattery) has a fragment that registers for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` in `onResume()` and unregisters in `onPause()`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2014 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.battmon;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BatteryFragment extends Fragment {
  private ProgressBar bar=null;
  private ImageView status=null;
  private TextView level=null;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.batt, parent, false);

    bar=(ProgressBar)result.findViewById(R.id.bar);
    status=(ImageView)result.findViewById(R.id.status);
    level=(TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.level);

    return(result);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter f=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);

    getActivity().registerReceiver(onBattery, f);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(onBattery);

    super.onPause();
  }

  BroadcastReceiver onBattery=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      int pct=
          100 * intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 1)
              / intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 1);

      bar.setProgress(pct);
      level.setText(String.valueOf(pct));

      switch (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1)) {
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
          status.setImageResource(R.drawable.charging);
          break;

        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:
          int plugged=
              intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

          if (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC
              || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB) {
            status.setImageResource(R.drawable.full);
          }
          else {
            status.setImageResource(R.drawable.unplugged);
          }
          break;

        default:
          status.setImageResource(R.drawable.unplugged);
          break;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

As a result, it will only receive that broadcast while the fragment is in the foreground from an input standpoint.

Comment: Yes it is that I want it to work on all the activity of the application but I would only stop when I leave the application. Please I start, I do not understand too ..

Comment: @Antholife: I do not know what "leave the application" means in technical terms. If this is a single-activity application, you could call `registerReceiver()` in `onStart()` and `unregisterReceiver()` in `onStop()`, for example.

Comment: When the application is scanned in recent apps :) Yes but I need more details, I am a novice, thank you :)

Comment: @Antholife: I added a sample of using `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: Yes Thanks ! I look later , Thanks :)

Comment: For sms, what I put in place of ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED?

Comment: @Antholife: Use [`SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION) or the equivalent string value (`"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`).

Comment: I do not understand .. yes that's what's in the manifest, but it is red .. Sorry for my level ...

Comment: @Antholife: Replace `new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)` with `new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")`. "yes that's what's in the manifest, but it is red" -- remove the `<receiver>` element from your manifest. If you are using `registerReceiver()` for this broadcast, you are no longer using `<receiver>`.

Comment: thank you it works but one more thing, getActivity indicates a error of method:(

Answer (score 1):

[check this](http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html) and register/unregister at right place.

Comment: You can either do as in the tutorial or you can register/unregister for each activity in your application like CommonsWare's answer. Although that may be too heavy for the app, if your activities transition frequently.